# A vector image shows up in grayscale when the ios app is run

Tags: ios, pdf, uiimageview

I have added a image PDF file to the Assets.xcassets with "Preserve Vector Data" enabled and Scales set to "Single Scale". The link to PDF file is http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=23770511818271314951

The PDF file has colours and is not in grayscale.

When the image of an `UIImageView` is set to this image asset, and the app is run, the image is shown in grayscale.

Can anyone point out why this is happening?
Can anyone point out how to show the image with color?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but perhaps iOS is not handling the Pattern dictionary correctly (a bug) or there is some other API setting you need to use for it to be displayed correctly.

I tried various types of PDF software and nobody displayed it as grayscale so that tends to point the finger back to iOS.